# Android - Display Ads in ported BB Playbook App?

Tags: android, blackberry-playbook

I wanted to port my Android App to BB PB but then I noticed that none of my AdMob Ads where displaying. So I thought this might be because most of the AdMob Ads refere to Android Apps on the Playstore. Therefore these can't be displayed because the PB hasn't got a Play Store.
 
My Question:
 
How can I display Ads in my Android-PB App? Is there a solution for AdMob Ads or should I use an other service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't display any Admob ads in Playbook currently, the current workaround I use it to use Google mobile AdSense and display it in webview or alertdialog and it works great but this is not a good practice

Does your log show
`01-22 18:24:37.290: I/Ads(29835418): onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.)` ?

check this link too http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Android-Runtime-Development/No-Admob-in-Android-app/td-p/1373097

Comment: can you please give a short example, how you can display AdSense Ads in a WebView?

Comment: I have asked an other question regarding this subject. It is worth 50 bounty. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119654/android-adsense-in-webview-for-blackberry-playbook-android-runtime#comment14669915_11119654