# Android - AdSense in WebView (for BlackBerry Playbook - Android Runtime)

Tags: android, webview, adsense, blackberry-playbook

I would like to diplay AdSense Ads in A WebView in Android.
I know I could just take AdMob Ads but I am Developing for the Playbook and the Playbook has just got an Android Virtual Runtime, therefore most of the AdMob ads are not displayed because they target an Android App on the Play Store and because the Playbook hasnt got a Play Store, it won't show up. So I would rather user AdSense Ads, but I don't know how to use them, I ave got no experience in Web Development. Can someone give me some tips how to archive this?

So far I have just got a WebView set up at the bottom of the App.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think AdMob needs Play store to work. You can also add a link to where the apk file can be downloaded afaik.

Comment: that was just an example... I meant 95% of the AdMob ads are mot displayed in the Playbook Android Runtime... that isn't just my problem, its a very common problem in the Blackberrry-Android Community. Thats the only solution I could come of to deal with that problem(using AdSense insted of AdMob) :)

Comment: Ok sorry, misunderstood then. I hope the answer will be fast there for you then.

Comment: https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181960&topic=28896&ctx=topic

Comment: I don't think Adsense would work here. The idea of Adsense is that the it looks at the other content on the same page to determine what ads to show. In your case, there is no other content to use.

Comment: I am using admob in playbook android , which works fine.in webview. For your information you can use AdSense for mobile too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember reading that AdSense on mobile Apps is against the Google Guidelines(But im not that entirely sure about that).

Comment: You can use "Adsense for Mobile" http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=68724

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you can use AdSense in WebView, it's not against Google policy. However, you can't use AdSense directly in the app itself.